# CSS animation interfering with transform transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I want to apply a hover animation on the class `circle` and on click of the `circle` I want it to transition smoothly to its desired position but I can't get that transition to work. Without the hover animation, the transition works fine, but as soon as I add the animation on hover, the transition doesn't apply anymore.

Here's the code

```
<div class="doc">
<!--   TRANSITION NOT WORKING W/ HOVER ANIMATION -->
  <div id="mainContainer" class="container">
  <div id="circle" class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: red;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.move {
  transform: translateX(50px);
}

.container:hover > .circle {
  animation: moveUp 1s infinite ease;
}

.container:hover > .move {
  animation: none;
}


@keyframes moveUp {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```js
document.getElementById("mainContainer").onclick = function() {
var element = document.getElementById("circle");
  element.classList.add("move");
}
```

And here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/bshm0xca/58/

The box on the right is the desired transition effect
The box on the left has a hover animation, but once I click on the container, the circle will snap to the transformed position instead of transitioning to it.

Why is this happening?? How do I get the circle to animate on hover and transition on click?

Thank you!

Comment: I think it'd be easier if you wrap around `.circle` a parent div, then control its state on its own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the sample I've put together below, please be noticed that I had to insert a div for controlling the `circle` transition state. Not mixing the duration of `animation` and `transition`.

For more complex animation sequence, you should have a look at [`transition` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event)

```js
document.getElementById("mainContainer").onclick = function() {
    const element = document.getElementById("circle");
    element.classList.toggle("move");
  
  element.addEventListener('transitionstart', () => {
    element.classList.add('moving')
  });
  
  element.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    element.classList.remove('moving');
  });
}
```

```css
.doc {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle {
  transition: all 2.5s ease;
}

.circle-bubble {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: red;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.move {
  transform: translateX(50px);
}

.container:hover .circle:not(.moving) .circle-bubble {
  animation: moveUp .5s infinite ease;
}


@keyframes moveUp {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-15px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="doc">
  <div id="mainContainer" class="container">
    <div id="circle" class="circle">
      <div class="circle-bubble"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked - I don't understand why you necessarily need to have a container dedicated to control the animation though (I tried without it and the animation didn't work) why is it necessary?

Comment: For example, if I take away the `circle-bubble` class and do as follow:

```
.container:hover .circle:not(.moving).circle:not(.move) {
  animation: moveUp 1s infinite ease;
}
```

Why does it end up snapping instead of transitioning again?
fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/89k0grnb/15/

Comment: please have a look at this sample https://jsfiddle.net/j07hq34y/ , I tried to use only one div, increasing the time duration to 3s and see how things work. The takeaway point here is using both `animation` and `transition` might mess up your animation intention because of its state. `transform` won't combine the current value like `transformX(50px) transformY(-8px)`, that's why you see it snapping. In real scenario try to break down into small parts so you can control easier

Comment: Your CSS selector ` .container:hover .circle:not(.moving).circle:not(.move)` was wrong, it should be `.container:hover .circle:not(.moving)`

Answer (score 0):

You have just to use pseudo-selector `:hover` and `:active` without js.

Comment: The problem in this case is, if I have a hover animation on the circle and I want it to move to X=10 on click, the transition effect isn't being applied - the circle just snaps to X=10. I want it to apply the `transition: all 1s ease;` Does this make sense?

Comment: You seem to have overwritten most of your answer with your last edit @okirim. Can you do a new edit that contains all relevant parts of your answer please?